# Защита VisualSvn при переменовании файлов в проектах не входящих в ревизию

Tags: visual-studio

Кто знает, как можно убрать защиту `VISUAL-SVN` при переименовании файлов в проектах, которые не входят в ревизию?

Например, есть `Solution`:

```
-DemoSolution  
 +DemoProjetc1
 +DemoProjetc2 (*)
 +DemoProjetc3 (*)
```

Вот где стоит (*) эти проекты входят в ревизию, а `DemoProjetc1` - не входит, но он сюда добавлен что бы можно было корректировать - это вспомогательная библиотека (можно всё это вытащить сразу через `dll`, но каждый раз копировать туда - долго, да и 2 VS надо будет открывать) вот, когда я пытаюсь переименовать файл в `DemoProjetc1 - VISUAL-SVN` мне выводит сообщение:

> .....\DemoProjetc1 .csproj' is not a working copy.

и не переименовывает...
Как можно это обойти?

Answer (score 1):

Это баг. Фикс будет в одном из следующих резлизов VisualSVN.

Update: было исправлено в VisualSVN 3.0.0.